# how to customize logging in laravel 5,7

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I read "laravel5.7" manual. And put customize monolog class into tap options in "logging.php", but it not working.

This is for "laravel5.7",PHP 7.2.11-4

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single'],
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'tap' => [App\Log\CustomizeFormatter::class],
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],
 ]

class CustomizeFormatter
{
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        $dateFormat = "Y n j, g:i a";
        $output = "%datetime% > %level_name% > %message% %context% extra%\n";
        $formatter = new LineFormatter($output, $dateFormat);
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
                $handler->setFormatter($formatter);
            }
    }
}
```

I expect I can customize logging and write the extra column into the log.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __invoke($logger)
{
    foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
        $handler->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
            $record['extra']['id'] = $GLOBALS['log_id'];
            $record['extra']['app'] = config('app.name');
            return $record;
        });
        $format = "[%datetime%] [%extra.id%] [%extra.app%] [%level_name%] [%message%] [%context%]\n";
        $ll =  new LineFormatter($format, null, true, true);
        $handler->setFormatter($ll);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use it customize your log